# How to deploy a config file with Azure DevOps Continuous Deployment?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nlog

How can I bring these NLog files to Azure DevOps

[image]

Now that I'm using Azure DevOps I would like to remove these

- NLog.Development.config
- NLog.Staging.config
- NLog.Release.config

files from my project and insert them in my deployment package on DevOps Continuous Deployment Pipeline.

I already have 2 tasks

[image]

1. to modify the app.config file.
2. to copy the binaries to working folder

Is it possible to add a task to copy my entire NLog config from somewhere (but not in my project repository) to my working folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a task to copy my entire NLog config from somewhere (but not in my project repository) to my working folder?

Yes. We can achieve this in Continuous Deployment Pipeline.

Since you need to save the Nlog config files out of the Project Repo, I suggest that you can upload the NLog files to secure file (**Pipelines -> Library -> Secure files**).

In Release Pipeline, you can use the task [Download secure file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) to download the related files.

The file will be download to the temp folder. You can use the predefined variable：  `$(Agent.TempDirectory)` to get the folder path. File path: `$(Agent.TempDirectory)/NLog.config`

Then you can use the Copy file task to copy the related NLog.config file to working folder.

Here is an example:

[image]

On the other hand, you can also save the files to a new Repo and then you can add repo artifacts in Release Pipeline to get the files. Or you can save the files to other service(e.g. Storage account) and add additional steps to get the files and copy it to working folder.